# Is there a perfect code generation tool to generate MVC Storefront?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-generation, ddd-repositories

Does anybody know a good code generation tool (other than Subsonic because it doesn't support IQueryable in current version) to generate repository and other projects in a way Rob Conery worked in MVC Storefront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob Conery has put out a Visual Studio plug-in that generates MVC code, using repositories that use IQueryable, although I believe the model is generated using Linq to SQL classes in visual studio, which wasn't the case in MVC Storefront.

You can find it [here](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/subsonic-mvc-adding-updated-for-beta-1/).

Comment: The links posted here are no longer accessible. Should these be updated / the question archived?

Answer (score 1):

S#arp Architecture may be overkill, but if you haven't checked it out already, I would recommend. It has a very nice tutorial as part of the download as well as a working Northwind sample.

Answer (score 0):

Updated on comment request.

Is [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022) the answer for your needs?

Also look at [Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).

Comment: The links posted here are no longer accessible. Should these be updated / the question archived?

Comment: @KumarC and others the links have been fixed and added another.